# CSS creating a parent class for bootstrap (SiteBuilder Lite)

Tags: html, css

Thanks. First of all Id like to stay that this is no ordinary problem.. Im a php developer and mostly concentrate on backend development.

Ive come across a hurdle.

basically what im trying to do is this

```
.parentclass {

 .a-bunch-of-bootstrap-children {

 }

}
```

I know its possible to do:

```
.parentclass .child-class {}
```

But that is not quite what im looking for. See, that would require me to change everything and there are a lot of variations.

Im working on a website/template builder system (SiteBuilder Lite) some of you may know this system.

Im implementing new templates into the system or "blocks" as they call it.

Now, the system uses a skeleton.html to build a template. It contains all of the assets to be included. including all css files and does not allow for specific files to be loaded per site.

Now, we load 1 main bootstrap style. But other templates have different bootstrap styles. So what i wanted to do was just enclose a template file inside a parent div and then have all the bootstrap children be formatted accordingly without tampering with the main bootstrap style and adding different parent classes and styles for each.

I know this is not the most efficient way to do this so if anyone has any suggestions please do suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.parentclass {

 .a-bunch-of-bootstrap-children {

 }
}
```

It's absolutely possible to use this syntax in SCSS actually.

Sicne SCSS is fully compatible with CSS, the only thing you have to do is to change your filename from `.css` to `.scss`, and then use a SCSS compiler to export all your customized bootstrap css files.

[Compass](http://compass-style.org/install/) would be a good choice for you if you are not using Gulp or Grunt or other task builder.

Though I'm not quite familiar with `SiteBuilder Lite`, the following steps should work:

1. Add a wrapper tag `<div id="customized-page-1"></div>` in `skeleton.html`
2. Change your customized css filenames from `page-1.css` to `page-1.scss`
3. In `page-1.scss` file, add your nested selector `#customized-page-1` to wrap the original css rules
4. Install Compass
5. Go to your scss folder and run `compass compile` in the command line
6. You'll now see the compiled css files with the same filename
7. Done!

Comment: Hi,

So Compass is great. Sass is just great but ive ran into another problem.

Bootstrap gets utterly destroyed when i use a parent div.

Comment: Well, it's kind of vague about which part is break. I'll assume the problem might be caused by the grid system you used. If this is the case, just add `class="container"` on your parent `<div>` so the child grid may get the same context.

Comment: Hi Sorry i was on the road and my reply got cut. ill be home in a few. Thanks for your support. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Hi Sorry,

I did what you recommended and for the most part it fixes some of the problems. 

However, I have noticed that offset does not work even when inside a container and a row. It seems to ignore offset. Everything from sm to lg i have tried.

Comment: Hi,

Okay thanks for your comment after adding container to the parent divs it seems to have fixed most problems, but 1:

offset does not work.. I have tried from xs to lg and none of these work. do you possibly know what the problem might be? 

p.s. in my css files I needed to add a container max-width property.

Comment: Maybe show your layout issue on the [Codepen](http://codepen.io/)?
By the way, if you set the max-width to the container it would break the original Bootstrap grid system for sure.

If what you want to do is limit the width according to different screen size, just try use `col-xs-*` and `col-md-*` for different screen size, rather then just limit the max-width on the container.